# Eclipse maven build does not install dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm working in eclipse on a java / javascript project, we're using maven to manage our project dependencies, I ran into a issue with maven build (clean install) does not install the dependencies that I specified in the POM.xml file, I tried everything I can find on the internet the whole day today, still no luck, I'll be really appreciate if anyone could kindly take a look at, thank you :)

I got a reuse lib project (lib) and a working project (project), the project should be installing the lib during the maven build, So, here's more detail information on what exactly I did:

1. I ran maven clean on the lib, then ran maven package, the lib-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file was generated successfully.
2. then in the working project POM.xml file, I added the dependency declaration.
3. I right clicked the working project, maven -> update maven project, where I checked the 'force update of snapshots / releases' checkbox, then -> ok
4. I right clicked the working project, run as -> maven build (with clean install, and also I checked on the 'Update Snapshots' checkbox) -> apply -> run

In the console, I saw the reuse lib was downloading and then downloaded, but it's never got installed (there should be a line says installing reuse lib...), as the result of it, the reuse lib will not be loaded after I ran my working project, it drives me insane -_-!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only **your** maven projects build output can be installed (in the local repository with `mvn install`, resp. `mvn clean install`). During the build it will resolve the dependencies (and the transitive dependencies) to be downloaded and packed to your delivery. Those dependencies of your project will implicitly also be "installed" in your local repository since you will see them in your local repository after the download happened - Maven will however not see that as a `install` in the meaning of `install` of the default lifecycle.

To install your "reuse lib"-Maven project you will have to run `mvn install` or `mvn clean install` on that project's pom rather than on a project which "just uses it as dependency".

Comment: Hey, I've been wondering about this too, but in Netbeans. Is there really no way to automatically clean and install dependencies of which you also have the source code locally? Netbeans actually detects the code is also a Netbeans project so I was wondering if it's not possible to automatically propagate my clean install command.

Comment: @warkst i am currenty not aware of a IDE based solution for this - what i tend to do when workig on multiple projects that have dependencies between them is to create a new maven project that defines all of the other maven projects as its modules (only unidirectional so zou dont need to change anything inside the other poms) - then clean install this project (will call clean install on all of your other maven projects) hope that helps